How to work with audio in my os i386 (for example, sound blaster 16)
I need a way to play sound at a certain frequency for a while in C without libraries (the most important thing). How can this be implemented, for example, on the sound blaster 16 audio card (AC97 is also possible)
I have implemented the outb and inb functions. I use qemu in kali (or Oracle Virtual box)
My try to do it:
#include "defs.h"
#include "sound/audio_card.h"
#include "asm.h"


void sb16_reset() {
    outb(1, SB16_DSP_RESET);  // Сброс устройства
    delay(1000);              // Задержка
    outb(0, SB16_DSP_RESET);  // Выход из режима сброса
    
    // Ожидание ответа от DSP
    while (!(inb(SB16_DSP_READ) & 0x80));
    if (inb(SB16_DSP_READ) != 0xAA) {
        // Ошибка инициализации
        // Добавьте обработку ошибок
    }
}

// Отправка команды DSP
void sb16_send_command(uint8_t cmd) {
    while (inb(SB16_DSP_WRITE) & 0x80);  // Ожидание готовности
    outb(cmd, SB16_DSP_COMMAND);
}

// Установка частоты выборки
void sb16_set_sample_rate(uint16_t hz) {
    sb16_send_command(0x40);  // Команда для установки частоты
    outb((hz >> 8), SB16_DSP_WRITE);    // Старший байт
    outb((hz & 0xFF), SB16_DSP_WRITE);  // Младший байт
}

// Отправка данных для воспроизведения
void sb16_write_data(uint8_t data) {
    while (inb(SB16_DSP_WRITE) & 0x80);  // Ожидание готовности
    outb(data, SB16_DSP_BUFFER);         // Отправка данных в буфер
}

// Воспроизведение звука (упрощённо)
void sb16_play_sound(uint16_t freq, uint32_t duration_ms) {
    sb16_reset();  // Инициализация SB16
    sb16_set_sample_rate(freq);  // Установка частоты

    // Начало воспроизведения
    sb16_send_command(0xC6);  // Включение режима 8-битного моно-режима
    
    // Передача данных для простого звука (например, прямоугольная волна)
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < duration_ms; i++) {
        sb16_write_data(128);  // Пример отправки данных
        sb16_write_data(255);  // Пример отправки данных (генерация простого сигнала)
        delay(500);            // Небольшая задержка между пакетами данных
    }
    
    // Остановка воспроизведения
    sb16_send_command(0xD0);  // Остановить воспроизведение
}

#define SB16_DSP_RESET 0x226
#define SB16_DSP_READ  0x22A
#define SB16_DSP_WRITE 0x22C
#define SB16_DSP_COMMAND 0x22C
#define SB16_DSP_BUFFER  0x22E
#define M_PI 3.1415

Sorry for the Russian comments, I'm Russian myself and writing English comments is not convenient :)

Does your code do what you expected or not?  Have you read https://wiki.osdev.org/Sound_Blaster_16?  It has some info about doing DMA of a buffer of PCM samples, and setting up QEMU to support it.

"Does your code do what you expected or not?" - no. "Have you read wiki.osdev.org/Sound_Blaster_16" - for me its not working.
